# Could not create an issue in Jira using CLI when component name contains comma

Tags: command-line, jira, jira-cli

I am using **Jira Command Line interface**(v. 3.9.0) to create Jira Issue. Everything works well until there is a comma in component name. 
Here is an example of parameters I used for **createIssue** action:

```
--project "MyProj" --type "MyType" --summary "Some summary" --description "Test desc" --components "Company, Inc."
```

`"Company, Inc"` is the single component. But according to the documentation (https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JCLI/Documentation#Documentation-components) Jira expects list of the components separated by commas in the **--components** parameter. Therefore Jira thinks that "Company, Inc" is 2 components - "Company" and "Inc."

Is there a way to create issue with such component?

EDIT:
According to the tips on documentation page (https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JCLI/Tips) values containing a comma must be enclosed in single quotes. However it didn't help too.

Comment: Just a thought: try using `\,` or `^,`

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work.

Comment: Try single quotes then and not double quotes.

Answer (score 3):

According to:
https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JCLI/Tips

the comma is a "problmatic" character, but you can provide an alternate character to be used in your commands. For example, by adding this:

–special "#    "

to your CLI command, you can then use the hashtag symbol INSTEAD OF the comma in your CLI command.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I saw that tip, but it is unclear where should I put –special "# ". And as far as I understood # is alternative for colon (:).

Comment: The "#" symbol is an alternative to the colon in their example only, it can be used as a replacement for other characters. If you use -special "# ", then "#" is in the first position, thus replacing the comma. If you put the "#" in the second position (i.e. -special " # ", then it is replacing the colon. That's what the "position" column means in the section about special characters. It is a bit obscure, but it works  ; )

Comment: You could try simply adding --special "#    " to your CLi command above.

Comment: It didn't help. Jira still parses comma.